# twentythirteen h1 and h2 not resizing responsively

Tags: responsive

I'm using the twentythirteen theme which is supposed to be responsive, here on my [site](http://www.daltonpharmacy.com).

On this static homepage, the text-headers are generated as follows, using the heading tags:

```
<h2>Hello!</h2>
```

If you narrow the width of the page, you will see the page title "Home" shrink in size, but the text-headers don't. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to access your style sheet (style.css). Your site uses [media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619217/can-someone-please-explain-css-media-queries) to target specific screen sizes and apply different rules when the stylesheet interacts with them.

In section 4.1, it defines the site title as:

```
.site-title {
    font-size: 60px;
}
```

In Section 8.0, just beneath `@media (max-width: 643px)` it defines the site title as:

```
.site-title {
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

In other words, when the screen size is less than or equal to 643px wide, the site title adjusts to 30px.

In your case, you'd want your Section 8 include a rule for h2 (exchanging the # for the desired number of pixels:

```
.site-title {
    font-size: 30px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: #px;
}
```